# selenium get page source different with right click in browser

Tags: javascript, jquery, python-2.7, selenium

I am having problem parse a web page, since I get different page source when I do:

```
display = Display(visible=False, size=(800, 600), backend='xvfb')
display.start()
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
url = "http://www.aaa.com"
driver.get(url)
with codecs.open('page.html', 'w', 'utf-8') as f:
    f.write(driver.page_source)
```

When I open the file to see the actual text, it is different with what I get with right click in browser.

For example, some href become lower case.
And some tag in page source:

```
<table class="list" boroder="0" id="list_id">
```

turned into

```
<table border="0" id="list_id" class="list">
```

I am pretty sure it is the same url I am requesting...

Comment: The order of tags and the case of hrefs don't matter actually. What is the reason you care about it?

Comment: @alecxe Because I have to parse the html, it doesn't work the same way when using selenium and saving page source to file.

Comment: if you need to parse it, then as @alecxe says it doesn't matter. if you are having issues with your parser, then that is a huge problem, and switch to a different one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two major issues at play in getting the source of a web page like you are doing.

1. Although we describe web pages using HTML, browsers don't work with HTML directly. They convert the HTML to an internal representation called a DOM tree. What `driver.page_source` and saving the source of a file to disk do is transform this DOM tree back to HTML in a process called serialization. Two serializers, or a single serializer which is used with two different configurations, can serialize the **same** DOM tree **differently**. You've encountered one such case with:

   ```
   <table class="list" border="0" id="list_id">
   ```

   versus

   ```
   <table border="0" id="list_id" class="list">
   ```

   In the two instances above, the order of attributes is different. However, it does not matter because *attributes* are not ordered in HTML. (Elements, and the tags that mark the start and end of elements, are ordered. So `<a><b>` is not the same as `<b><a>`.) Other differences could occur due to the way the serializers handle spacing. Names could also differ in capitalization: `<TABLE>` and `<table>` are equivalent. This is because HTML is not case-sensitive (XHTML is case-sensitive.)

   There is no guarantee that Selenium and Firefox's save menu are going to use the exact same serializer with the exact same configuration. So there may be differences between what you get from the two methods.
2. Another thing that may cause you trouble is Ajax. It is not rare nowadays that a web page does not initially contain all the elements that it needs. Some of these elements are loaded shortly after the initial page has finished loading. If you save the page from `driver.page_source` *after* the page has initially loaded but *before* the Ajax has had a chance to load the additional elements, and then you manually save the page using Firefox's menu, chances are that some differences will occur because `driver.page_source` misses the elements loaded through Ajax.