# Different page's source code between selenium and the browser itself

Tags: python, firefox, selenium

I'm writing a tool that one of his actions should be analyze web pages sources.
I'm using Selenium for Python with Firefox driver.
When I tried to get the source code of the page, with `webdriver.page_source` command, I got different source than the one I got from the regular one (Right click inside the browser -> Page Source).
I used hooking to the browser that should add text to the page (I saw that text in the regular page source, but can't see it via selenium)

For example:

Source code from the browser:

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
    <div>THIS DIV INJECTED TO THE BROWSER</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Source code from Selenium:

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <title>Title</title>
    <h1>Test Page</h1>
  </body>
</html>
```

I saw a similar post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22463894/selenium-get-page-source-different-with-right-click-in-browser), but the answer there was not relevant.

Please note that I need the **source code** itself, and not the rendered code (that I get with `webdriver.execute_script`.

How can I get the regular source code?

Comment: Different *how*, exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I edited the question now.

Comment: ...but it still doesn't really answer my question. A [mcve] is required.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most possible issue here is the wait problem - you are *getting the page source when the page is not completely loaded*. Your best option to approach the problem is to add an [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits) to wait for a specific element to become present/visible:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebdriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "myid")))

print(driver.page_source)
```

Comment: I'm not sure where the `driver.get(<requestedURL>)` takes place here

Comment: @Dan well, this is just a relevant part of the code, `driver.get()` would definitely goes before doing `wait.until()`.